# Stokes theorem problem $\displaystyle \int_C (3y+z)dx+(x^2 +2yz)dy+(2x+y^2)dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let
>
> $
> S_1=\{(x,y,z)   \  | \ x^2+y^2-2x-2y+1=0   \}
> $
>
> $
> S_2=\{(x,y,z)   \  | \ 2x+3y+z=9   \}
> $
>
> and $C=S_1\cap S_2$

I'd like to calculate following integral

> $$
> \int_C (3y+z)dx+(x^2 +2yz)dy+(2x+y^2)dz\
> \\\
> $$
>   the orientation of $C$ :
>
> projection of $C$ on xy-plane will be anticlockwise

$$
$$

I'd like to solve this with ***Stokes thm***. So I did...

$$\int_C (3y+z)dx+(x^2 +2yz)dy+(2x+y^2)dz\\\
=\iint_D (0,-1,2x-3)\cdot(2,3,1)dS \\\
=\iint_D (2x-6)dS
$$
where D is the region surrounded $C$. (D must be a ellipse)

$$
$$

How can I solve the rest thing?

If I have $\iint_D dS$ ( instead of $\iint_D (2x-6)dS$ ) , then I will calculuate the stretch of ellipse D.

But... in this time I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the right integral. First, you need to parametrize the region you want to use, which is an ellipse in this case. $S_1$ is an ellispe, $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$; $S_2$ is a plane, $z=9-2x-3y$. The parametrization is then:

$$\mathbf{A}(r,\theta)=\langle r(1+\sin \theta), r(1+\cos \theta),9-2r(1+\sin \theta)-3r(1+\cos \theta)\rangle ,$$

with $0\leq r\leq 1$ and $0\leq \theta <2\pi$. You found $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\langle 0,-1, 2x-3\rangle$ and using Stokes' theorem:

$$\iint_S \nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_0^{2\pi} \! \! \! \int_0^{1} \langle 0,-1, 2x-3\rangle \cdot \biggl | \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial r} \times \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial \theta}\biggr| \, dr\, d\theta  .$$

That $x$ in the integral needs to be replaced by $r(1+\sin \theta)$. Finding the determinant $\biggl | \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial r} \times \dfrac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial \theta}\biggr|$ is cumbersome, but there you have it, an "ugly" integral.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'll study about it more and more.